# Limit to at most 3 result laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I try to make referral query limit to 3 level of users referral system. The original codes give unlimited level of referrals.

```
    public function referralUsers($id, $currentLevel = 1)
    {
        $users = $this->getUsers($id);
        if ($users['status']) {
            $this->allusers[$currentLevel] = $users['user'];
            $currentLevel++;
            $this->referralUsers($users['ids'], $currentLevel);
        }
        return $this->allusers;
    }
    
    public function getUsers($id)
    {
        if (isset($id)) {
            $data['user'] = User::whereIn('referral_id', $id)->get(['id', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'username', 'email', 'phone_code', 'phone', 'referral_id', 'created_at']);
            if (count($data['user']) > 0) {
                $data['status'] = true;
                $data['ids'] = $data['user']->pluck('id');
                return $data;
            }
        }
        $data['status'] = false;
        return $data;
    }
```

I tried to limit the db query by adding `->limit(3)` and `->take(3)` but not working

```
$data['user'] = User::whereIn('referral_id', $id)->limit(3)->get(['id', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'username', 'email', 'phone_code', 'phone', 'referral_id', 'created_at']);
```

and

```
$data['user'] = User::whereIn('referral_id', $id)->take(3)->get(['id', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'username', 'email', 'phone_code', 'phone', 'referral_id', 'created_at']);
```

If I can't limit the db query, how to limit the result in the `$currentLevel++`

I am new to laravel codes.

Thanks!

Comment: *"I tried to limit the db query by adding `->limit(3)` and `->take(3)` but not working"* - What do you mean by "not working" here? `limit()` or `take()` both add a limit clause to your SQL query, which should restrict the # of records returned. If you run `count(User::limit(3)->get())`, what do you get? I couldn't recreate an issue with your code...

Comment: @TimLewis It means no effect at all. no error with same result. I think it is a more complex db query as it is not rely on single refferal_id but multiple. so instead of limiting the db query, i try to focusing on limiting the result in php codes. as you can see, the default value of the `$currentLevel` is 1, I want to limit it to 3. do you know how?

Comment: Ok, I think I see what you're trying to do. You're incrementing `$currentLevel` every time you recursively call, but you're never checking `if ($currentLevel > 3) { ... }`, so of course this will provide "unlimited" levels (or until `$data['status']` is `false`). This code is a little confusing, especially since `$id` (a singular word) is actually an Array of multiple ids, and just the nature of recursion in general...

Comment: thanks @TimLewis it works with this code ````$currentLevel++;
   if ($currentLevel == 4) { 
    return false; 
   }````

Comment: Nice! Yeah, with recursive functions, if you don't specify a break condition like that, it'll continue running until it either hits another exit condition (like your `if ($users['status'])` check), enters too many layers (255 nested recursions, I think), or you run out of memory. Glad you got it working 

Comment: have you tried to put ->take(3) after the get?

this is a code I am using in one of my projects which works like a charm:

$this->product->reviews()->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get()->take(3);

Comment: @Larstton That would work, but the main issue with that is that `->get()` returns **ALL** the records specified in the query and loads them into a Collection. This could be incredibly poor performance-wise, since it could load _a lot_ of records into memory. `->take(3)` then returns the first 3 records from that loaded Collection. If you do `->take(3)->get()`, it'll only ever load up to 3 records, since it lets SQL do all the hard work. If you had a DB with a million records, `Table::get()->take(3)` would likely crash, while `Table::take(3)->get()` would work fine.

Comment: @TimLewis Also he can use some `order` and `where` clause to sort for more specific portions for this query. But yeah that should works just fine.

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco Of course, but if you're already using `->where()` to filter records in SQL, why not also limit it in SQL? `->where(...)->take(3)->get()` would almost always be more performant than `->where(...)->get()->take(3)`, unless there are literally only 3 records in that table; 4 or more would be loading those 4+ records into memory before doing an `array_slice($records, 0, 3)` (or whatever [`take()`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/collections#method-takehttps://laravel.com/docs/10.x/collections#method-take) does under the hood)

Comment: @TimLewis no doubt, you are absolutely right, we should use `->get()` as a final method to create (finalize) query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted this answer based on a discussion with @Tom Lewis in the comments section. Hopefully this answer can be useful for whom wants to build a limited tiered referral system.

My script by default uses an unlimited referral system and I want to limit it to a maximum of 3 levels.

The dB query recursively use `whereIn` to search for the `referral_id` in any level of the referral database. `User::whereIn('referral_id', $id)->get` and then return the result as `$currentLevel`.

It seems like limiting the dB query itself is not a good approach, so I try to focusing on limiting the level after the query result at the `$currentLevel`.

The solution end up very simple, I just need to limit the `$currentLevel` as my need to 3.

```
public function referralUsers($id, $currentLevel = 1)
    {
        $users = $this->getUsers($id);
        if ($users['status']) {
            $this->allusers[$currentLevel] = $users['user'];
           $currentLevel++;             
           if ($currentLevel == 4) { 
              return false; 
           }
            $this->referralUsers($users['ids'], $currentLevel);
        }
        return $this->allusers;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

With this modification, the referralUsers function will stop recursive calls once it reaches the third level of referrals, effectively limiting the query to 3 levels.

```
public function referralUsers($id, $currentLevel = 1) {
// Check if the current level exceeds 3
if ($currentLevel > 3) {
    return $this->allusers; // Return the collected users
}

$users = $this->getUsers($id);
if ($users['status']) {
    $this->allusers[$currentLevel] = $users['user'];
    $currentLevel++;
    $this->referralUsers($users['ids'], $currentLevel);
}
return $this->allusers;
}
```